# How to increase scroll button size in QGroupBox

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any style sheets to use to increase the size of scroll button size in QGroupbox. I have to change the default size.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "scroll buttons" within the `QGroupBox`. Perhaps you're referring to some other widget?